# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: inherited_resources doesn't call permitted_params

Tags: strong-parameters, inherited-resources

I have a Rails 4.0.2 application which relies on [nested_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources). Sadly, I'm getting an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when submitting my form (`#create`). My controller looks like the following:

```
class VocabulariesController < InheritedResources::Base
  def permitted_params
    params.permit(vocabulary: [:user_id, :name, :lang1, :lang2])
  end
end
```

I placed a `binding.pry` in `permitted_params` which is never caught, so the method is never actually called by inherited_resources.

Any idea what's wrong here?

**Update**

It seems that I didn't have the current version, although I did a `bundle update inherited_resources`. More infos here: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/350